# How to query Google Maps for directions with discrete address components?

Tags: google-maps, query-string

I want to build a Google Maps query for driving directions, but the code structure of my application requires separate fields.  That is, I can't say

```
?saddr=100+Main+St,Anytown,PA,02154
```

Instead I need to say

```
?saddr=100+Main+St&scity=Anytown&sstate=PA&szip=02154
```

I can change the names of the querystring parameters, but I can't omit them.

Anybody know what Google will accept?

Comment: You need to restructure your code and concatenate the values of the four fields before inserting it into the query string.

Answer (score 0):

Google maps will ignore the parameters it doesn't recognize so you can create the address in `saddr` and send the other parameters too.

```
?saddr=100+Main+St+Anytown,+PA+02154&scity=Anytown&sstate=PA&szip=02154
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't put the city, state and zip in the address string.  I can only get the four components separately, and assign each to an arbitrary querystring parameter.

Comment: What's the reason you can't change the parameters?

Comment: I'm looking for a way to do this with configuration, that doesn't require shipping new code to customers.  I may be able to rearrange the fields with Javascript before submitting the form, but it would be much nicer if there were some set of parameters that Google Maps would accept.